# create a list of Chinese names from another list

Tags: python, cjk

I have a list like this:

```
['/', '张', '茜', '/', '宗', '峰', '岩', '/', '何', '彦', '霓', '/', '周', '浩', '东', '/', '何', '思', '融', '/', '李', '林', '琳', '/', '赵', '卓', '娜', '/']
```

I would like to take these Chinese characters in between '/'s as these are names. i would like to build a list of names for next job. (a loyal customer with visit history or something.) something like the following:

```
[张茜,
 宗峰岩
...
]
```

I tried with following:

```
 import re
 ccl = re.findall(r'\/[\u4e00-\u9fff]+\/', castlist)
```

but it does not work.

thanks guys.

Comment: Is it about Python?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Python, the simplest approach here is to join all the characters and split on `/`, unless there's more to the question than you've presented:

```
''.join(list).split('/')
```

This will include some blank names:

```
['', '张茜', '宗峰岩', '何彦霓', '周浩东', '何思融', '李林琳', '赵卓娜', '']
```

You can avoid that either by getting rid of the leading and trailing `/` before you start, or by filtering the result to remove empty strings:

```
filter(None, ''.join(list).split('/'))
```